# Did they add new command line tools to Windows 8?

Tags: command-line, windows-8

I was wondering if they added any new tools to the Windows 8 command line?

Comment: How is this not constructive?

Comment: It dosen't tackle a specific problem - its basically a question that effectively asks for a list, and is open ended.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they have made changes to the command line tools available. Some have been added, and others removed.

New commands:

- **checknetisolation** - tests Windows Store App network capabilities
- **fondue** - AKA Features on Demand User Experience Tool, installs optional Windows 8 features
- **licensingdiag** - creates xml and cab files with installation and registration information
- **pwlauncher** - enable/disable/show Windows to Go startup options
- **register-cimprovider** - registers Common Information Model providers
- **tpmvscmgr** - creates/removes TPM virtual smart cards

Removed commands:

- **diantz** - duplicate of makecab
- **mount** - probably due to deprecation of Services for UNIX
- **nfsadmin** - probably due to deprecation of Services for UNIX
- **rcp** - probably due to deprecation of Services for UNIX
- **rpcinfo** - probably due to deprecation of Services for UNIX
- **rsh** - probably due to deprecation of Services for UNIX
- **showmount** - probably due to deprecation of Services for UNIX
- **umount** - probably due to deprecation of Services for UNIX
- **shadow**
- **rdpsign**

Commands with changes made to them:

- **format**

  - **/p** option - for data sanitization - meaning changed
- **netstat**

  - added **-x** switch
  - added **-y** switch
- **shutdown**

  - added **/o** switch
  - added **/hybrid** switch

Source: [New (and Removed) Commands in Windows 8](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/a/new-removed-commands-windows-8.htm)

Comment: @Nalaka526, please do not edit my post for such a minor change when it is still new, since I was still improving it

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry about that... Didn't want to disturb you... Sorry  again...

Comment: That was not a bad edit, and he can only suggested it, it was approved by a power user who has actual permissions to edit the post like 2k rep user can do that. The post was approved by a moderator so I don't think this was a bad edit, though he could reject it if he didn't find it good or reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Run CMD and use this list..

***New List Of Commands for Windows 8***

**Checknetisolation**

The checknetisolation command is a developer tool that can be used to test and troubleshoot the network capabilities of a Windows Store app from the Command Prompt

**Fondue**

The fondue command is no doubt one of the more memorable new commands in Windows 8. It stands for `Features on Demand User Experience Tool` and it's used to install any of the several optional Windows 8 features directly from the command line.

**Licensingdiag**

The licensingdiag command is actually a pretty handy tool. You define an XML and a CAB file to create and Windows 8 will generate both, full of information about your Windows 8 installation, specifically product activation and registration related data.

The most reasonable use for licensingdiag is to provide valuable activation troubleshooting information to Microsoft or some other support person.

**Pwlauncher**

The pwlauncher command is a command-line tool that can enable, disable, or show the current status of your Windows To Go start-up options

**Register-cimprovider**

The register-cimprovider command does just that - it registers CIM (Common Information Model) providers in Windows 8 from the command line.

**Tpmvscmgr**

The tpmvscmgr command is a full TPM virtual smart card tool, allowing both the creation and removal of smart cards

Besides that there are some commands that have been removed,the list of removed command can be found  [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/a/new-removed-commands-windows-8.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately that's just a list of all commands, but doesn't mention what's new or not. So, this is barely useful.

Comment: Fondue, reminds me of the 70's way to eat food in a horrible manner.